# TypeORM(MySQL) - Some relation entities are missing when take() used

Tags: node.js, orm, typeorm

I have 2 entities with the following relations,

User

```
@OneToMany(() => Photo, (photo) => photo.user)
photos: Photos[];
```

Photo

```
@ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.photos)  
@JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })  
user: User;
```

I use those entities in the following query. The expected result is that I receive the first 10 users with their photos. However, this query returns missing photos unless I add `photos.id` (PK of Photo entity) to the selected fields list.

```js
const users = await userRepo
    .createQueryBuilder('user')
    .leftJoin('user.photos', 'photos')
    .select([
      'user.id',
      'photos.url',
      'photos.timestamp',
    ])
    .take(10).getMany();
```

The same query works fine without `take(10)` being applied.

Moreover, when I check the raw result I can see that all of the photos are returned but TypeORM is not able to parse those photos to the entities for normal result.

I'd be happy if you can help me reason about this behavior. Thank you

Comment: Can you add the raw query to the post, use `.getQuery(`) or `.getSql()`

Answer (score 0):

Use entity manager and then refactored your query this way.

```
const users = await entityManager
.createQueryBuilder(User, 'user')
.leftJoinAndSelect('user.photos', 'photos')
.select('user')
.addSelect([
  'photos.url',
  'photos.timestamp',
])
.take(10).getMany();
```